# Where do the Parameters -Location1 and -Location2 in New-AzResourceGroupDeployment come from

Tags: powershell, parameters, azure-powershell

This week I am attending the AZ-104 training where I personally have some specific interest in Azure PowerShell were the training itself is actually more focused on administrating.
In several occasions, I have find myself questioning whether I have to revise my knowledge of PowerShell or simply over looking something as e.g. the command [`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment) in the [Lab 05 - Implement Intersite Connectivity
Student lab manual](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AZ-104-MicrosoftAzureAdministrator/Instructions/Labs/LAB_05-Implement_Intersite_Connectivity.html) which doesn't appear to have a `-Location1` or `-Location2` parameter (also not in the local help) but executes without any error...

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
  -TemplateFile $HOME/az104-05-vnetvm-loop-template.json `
  -TemplateParameterFile $HOME/az104-05-vnetvm-loop-parameters.json `
  -location1 $location1 `
  -location2 $location2
```

Where do the Parameters `-Location1` and `-Location2` in `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` come from?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azlocation?view=azps-9.5.0

Comment: @jdweng, does that mean `-Location1` and `-Location2` are a kind of [common parameters](‪https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) but than for azure?

Comment: No, it means that @jdweng has provided an irrelevant link (apparently prompted by the misconception that the word "location" in the command name is somehow relevant).

Comment: Yes, location in this case is common to all methods.

Comment: @jdweng, this question is about specific _parameters_, and the accepted answer addresses the question, unlike your comments, which are confusing distractions. There are no _methods_ here, only _cmdlets_, and the `Get-AzLocation` cmdlet you link to has _no_ such parameters, and they are certainly not _common_ parameters, which was iRon's question in a comment. As several times before, I implore you: please don't comment unless you understand the subject matter. I understand that you're trying to be helpful, but you're having the opposite impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **[*dynamic* parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters#dynamic-parameters)** that become available once you have specified a `-TemplateFile` or `-TemplateUri` argument, corresponding to the parameters defined in the given template file.

Quoting from the "Description" section of the [`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment) help topic (emphasis added; reformatted):

> To use a custom template to create a resource group, specify the
> `-TemplateFile` parameter or `-TemplateUri` parameter.
> Each template has parameters for configurable properties.
>
> To specify values for the template parameters, specify the `-TemplateParameterFile` parameter or the `-TemplateParameterObject` parameter.
>
> **Alternatively, you can use the template parameters that are *dynamically added to the command when you specify a template*.**
>
> To use dynamic parameters, type them at the command prompt, or type a minus sign (`-`) to indicate a parameter and use the Tab key to cycle through available parameters.
> **Template parameter values that you enter at the command prompt take precedence over values in a template parameter object or file**.

Comment: Of course , end of the (training) day... I was just scanning for the word `location` in the help, not realy reading it .

Comment: @iRon:  - truthfully, the way the information is presented doesn't exactly make it easy to spot and understand.